# Save my own plist after app closes

Tags: iphone

Whether plist that I created, and made changes while app running, will be saved even after killing the app? Or for saving data this way, I have to use CoreData, sqlite3 and stuff like that? Regards.

Comment: Have you considered using the `appWillTerminate` method of your appDelegate to save and close the file if it is still open?  To answer your question, yes I have saved a plist and then retrieved it after the app was closed and launched again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To save the plist when the app goes to the background, you have to add the code to save the plist in `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` method in app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

*After* your app has been killed you cannot do anything. That's like *After my death, I want to build a house* which you obviously can't do.

Quoting myself from an earlier question:

If have important things to save, you need to do so in the app delegate methods `applicationWillTerminate:` (iOS without multitasking) and `applicationDidEnterBackground:` (iOS with multitasking). It's also a good idea to save on `applicationDidResignActive:`. See the [UIApplicationDelegate reference](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Flibrary%2Fios%2Fdocumentation%2Fuikit%2Freference%2FUIApplicationDelegate_Protocol%2FReference%2FReference.html&ei=xqW_TZqRLYfQsgbzpoDDBQ&usg=AFQjCNFco4wGAzb5nDthm-Jp5cVDtXZFQg).

Note that all of these events also post NSNotifications to which you can subscribe to in any class you like. See the [notifications section in the UIApplication reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006728-CH3-DontLinkElementID_4).